# How to solve android studio project application when run than crashing after clicking on button

Tags: android

**Logcat error message**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskExecutors$zza cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at com.ea.messenger.auth.Verify.sendVerificationCode(Verify.java:238)
    at com.ea.messenger.auth.Verify.onCreate(Verify.java:115)
```

I am not able to identufy that whats the problem in the code pls tell how to solve this

**error code**

```
private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            (Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallbacks);
```

this is the code in which .getinstance and .verifyphonenumber is cutted

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            MainActivity.this, // this is current activity
            mCallbacks);
```

Comment: i tryed but it is still showing error the .getinstance and .verifyPhoneNumber text is cutted with a line over it

Answer (score 0):

```
PhoneAuthOptions options =
        PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                .setCallbacks(mCallBack)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                .build();
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

Comment: when i am applying this then it is showing more new errors